# What are some popular code generation engines?

Tags: code-generation

I've been using some Sonic and NHibernate and NetTiers.    What else is out there and how do they compare?

Comment: It rather depends on how you define code generation engines; an awful lot of things generate code nowadays.  Did you have any tools in mind that generate code for a specific task?

Answer (score 5):

Well, maybe it's not very cool, but I've been using `fprintf` to generate code ever since I learned C.

Comment: I've used that style of generation before; with Ruby, the built in eRB engine is great for code generation.

Comment: Hey, somebody, thanks for the downvote :-)  Nothing is more boring than stuff that everybody agrees with.

Answer (score 2):

On the unix side of things, autogen is pretty good: http://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/

I often use it to do poor man's templates in C (templating over float/double/long double),  but it can do some pretty advanced things too.

Answer (score 1):

[CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/?s=g1&gclid=CLiOhKHm-5oCFShRagodQTB-dw) is quite good.

Comment: I didn't neg it, but if he's already using NetTiers then he's probably using CodeSmith...  Though to be fair, NetTiers != CodeSmith so it still should be a valid answer...

Answer (score 1):

I've done a couple projects now where we used [T4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), which works pretty well and is built into Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The [GWT compiler](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideJavaToJavaScriptCompiler) is a cross-platform, optimising, Java-to-JavaScript code generator.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (reasonably) definitive list: http://www.codegeneration.net/generators.php

As for comparison, ultimately only you can decide if you want (or need) to adapt to the code they produce, or how much time you want to invest adapting your own style to align with what they produce.  For example, some developers here used LLBLGen for a while, but we have since abandoned its use as its output didn't align particularly well with our own coding standards.  It wasn't *bad* code, just different.

Comment: Seems a slightly drastic reason to abandon LLBLGen. a) You should hardly ever need to look at the generated code anyway and b) why not just modify the templates to make it match what you were after ?

Answer (score 0):

I hear a lot about [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/). I have also used ActiveWriter for CastleProject but it is a bit specific, not unlike subSonic though, which is more of an orm. (Activerecord uses NHibernate, but this is a tool to generate your classes.
As for generating classes, there is a built in class diagram system in Visual Studio to get you started.